# How to separate my plugin into multiple classes

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I use java and paper plugin. I made this myself, but it doesn't work well.

source code

```
package com;

import org.bukkit.event.Listener;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;


public class [[mainclassname]] extends JavaPlugin implements Listener {

    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().warning("Server started.");

        testing test = new testing(); // An error occurred that starts from here.
        test.onEnable();

        getLogger().info("Nice try!"); // check point
    }
}


class testing extends JavaPlugin {
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().warning("Hello!");
    }
}
```

build successful.

error : Error occurred while enabling [pluginname]  (Is it up to date?)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Plugin already initialized!

Comment: It's not possible. Why do you want to do it ?

Answer (score -1):

> The PluginAlreadyInitialized error occours when the .jar file contains more than one subclass of JavaPlugin class.

From [here](https://www.spigotmc.org/threads/plugin-already-initialized.40661/).

Comment: I cannot understand, could you let me know more details?

Comment: @nooob You cannot define two JavaPlugin on the same project or package and you are defining two.

Comment: Oh I found it already sorry };

Comment: @nooob And you got the same error?

Comment: No, but I couldn't have found how to fix.

Comment: @nooob then you have to open a new question